# Alert user when he tries to subtract when there is nothing else more to subtract

Tags: javascript, operators, dom-events, counter

I have a page with two buttons:

- One adds 1 unit of something to the user's inventory.
- The other removes 1 unit of that something from the user's inventory.
  For this example, that something will be diamonds.

Each time the user picks up or drops diamonds, a message will tell him how much diamonds he has in total.

I don't want those messages to be too generic like: "You have 1 diamond(s)".

I managed to generate different messages depending on the amount of diamonds the user has and if he is picking them up, or dropping them:

I would also like to have custom messages for when the user tries to pick up a diamond when his wallet is already full, and when he tries to drop one when he doesn't have any diamonds to drop. For example:

"You cannot pick any more diamonds. Your wallet is already full." and "You don't have any diamonds to drop."

And that's what I need help with.

As you will see in the code below, I have `diamondCount == 0` in the function that drops diamonds to generate the message "You dropped your last Diamond." If the user tries to drop another diamond from this point, the `diamondCount` will still be 0. So, how can I make it differentiate when the user just reached 0, and when he tried to drop a diamond, starting from 0?

This is what I have:

```js
        function pickDiamond() {
            if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                if (localStorage.diamondCount < 10) {
                    localStorage.diamondCount = Number(localStorage.diamondCount) + 1;
                } else {
                    localStorage.diamondCount = 10;
                }
                if (localStorage.diamondCount == 1) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You picked up your first Diamond!";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You picked up a Diamond. You now have a total of " + localStorage.diamondCount + " Diamonds in your wallet.";
                }
            }
        }

        function dropDiamond() {
            if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                if (localStorage.diamondCount > 0) {
                    localStorage.diamondCount = Number(localStorage.diamondCount) - 1;
                } else {
                    localStorage.diamondCount = 0;
                }
                if (localStorage.diamondCount == 1) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You dropped 1 Diamond. You only have 1 Diamond left in your wallet.";
                } else if (localStorage.diamondCount == 0) {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You dropped your last Diamond. You don't have any Diamonds now.";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You dropped a Diamond. You now have a total of " + localStorage.diamondCount + " Diamonds in your wallet.";
                }
            }
        }

        function dropAllDiamonds() {
            localStorage.diamondCount = 0;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You dropped all your Diamonds.";
        }
```

```html
    <p>Use the buttons to pick up or drop Diamonds</p>
    <p><button onclick="pickDiamond()" type="button">Pick up Diamonds</button></p>
    <p><button onclick="dropDiamond()" type="button">Drop Diamonds</button></p>
    <p><button onclick="dropAllDiamonds()" type="button">Drop All Diamonds</button></p>
    <p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is one of if/else logic. Specifically, you should be able to do everything you want with a single if/else chain. I did a few changes to your code as follows:

For pickDiamond, I started with your diamond count at zero and added new text down the logic train as the user's inventory increases. Dealing with numbers only, the incremental operator is appropriate here. Once the user's inventory reaches ten, the logic will default at "You cannot pick any more diamonds. Your wallet is already full." with the final else statement. I created a localStorage object for the sake of testing.

```
    let localStorage = {
        diamondCount: 0
    }
    function pickDiamond() {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (localStorage.diamondCount == 0) {
                localStorage.diamondCount++;
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You picked up your first Diamond!";
            } else if (localStorage.diamondCount < 10) {
                localStorage.diamondCount++;
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You picked up a Diamond. You now have a total of " + localStorage.diamondCount + " Diamonds in your wallet.";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You cannot pick any more diamonds. Your wallet is already full.";
            }

            }
        }
```

A similar solution can be used for the dropDiamond function except in reverse. The dropAllDiamonds function will work just fine unchanged.

```
        function dropDiamond() {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (localStorage.diamondCount > 2) {
                localStorage.diamondCount--;
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You dropped a Diamond. You now have a total of " + localStorage.diamondCount + " Diamonds in your wallet.";                 
            } else  if (localStorage.diamondCount == 2) {
                localStorage.diamondCount--;
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You dropped 1 Diamond. You only have 1 Diamond left in your wallet.";                    
            } else if (localStorage.diamondCount == 1) {
                localStorage.diamondCount--;
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You dropped your last Diamond. You don't have any Diamonds now.";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You don't have any Diamonds to drop ya dingus";
            }
        }
    }
        function dropAllDiamonds() {
             localStorage.diamondCount = 0;
             document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You dropped all your Diamonds.";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, mate! This is exactly what I needed. Nice touch with the dingus. I'm quite new to JavaScript. What does the `let localStorage = {diamondCount: 0};` do, exactly? Because it seems like everything works, without it....

Comment: No prob! Sorry I added that object for testing. I edited the answer to reflect that.